# How to prevent logs being written to the default /var/log/messages but only to the custom defined location?

Tags: linux, logging

Having already a defined custom rsyslog configuration like:

```
:msg, regex, "myappname", /appl/logs/myappname.log
```

How can I prevent the logs being written both on /var/log/messages and /appl/logs/myappname.log?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out as I should just add:

```
:msg, regex, "myappname" ~
```

as the 2nd line